# Angularjs File upload Is not showing File

Tags: angularjs

Im upload an image with Some Textbox Data at My two Way DataBinding TextBox Data is showing but why im not able to Seeing File Data

**Html code**

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" ng-model="customer.name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter LastName" ng-model="customer.LName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="customer.Mail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Avatar</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" file-model="customer.file">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="Submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
{{customer}}
```

```
 $scope.Submit = function () {
        debugger;
        var data = new FormData();
        console.log("customer", $scope.customer)


    _App.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        debugger;
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                var modelSetter = model.assign;
                element.bind('change', function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    }])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHeFJ.png)
Here i DIsplayed the Image Please Help me in {{customer}} Why im not getting File Data

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Afreen Ghouse don’t do that on submit call you calling directive, but it should also include try this instead of add directive before submit call and inject that directive in controller.

Comment: Do u have any pre solution